# Is there a more efficient way to code this conditional statement? Is there a max number of conditionals in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a list of about 100 place names and about the first 10 names begin with a numeral, which of course here is considered a string. I want to seperate the numbers and each letter. I tried this

```
if ($currentLetter == '0' || '1' || '2' || '3' ) etc.
```

but it always returned true even if the name began with a letter.

The code below works but seems inefficient to me, anyone have a more concise way to write this? Is there a max number of time you can use || in a statement?

```
 $lastLetter = 'z';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
 $the_query->the_post();
 // Show Posts ...
    $currentLetter = strtolower(substr(get_the_title(), 0, 1));
    $slug = basename(get_permalink());
    $proj_title = get_the_title();
    if ($currentLetter === '0' || $currentLetter === '1' || $currentLetter == '2' || $currentLetter == '3' || $currentLetter == '4' || $currentLetter == '4' || $currentLetter == '5' || $currentLetter == '6' || $currentLetter == '7' || $currentLetter == '8' || $currentLetter == '9') {
        //do nothing if a number
    } else if ($currentLetter != $lastLetter) {
            echo '<div class="row" style="border:1px solid gray;float:left;margin-top:48px;width:100%;height:auto;clear:both;"><h3 style="text-transform:uppercase;">';
            echo $currentLetter;
            echo '</h3></div>';
            $lastLetter = $currentLetter;
    }
    echo '<a href="'.$slug.'">'.$proj_title.'</a><br/>';

 endwhile;
```

Comment: is_numeric? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: If you just want to remove the digits at the front (not 100% sure which is why this is a comment) then just `ltrim()` off the digits - `ltrim($title, "0123456789");`

Comment: This is actually a code review question. But luckily you had a syntax error thus making it a valid SO question.

Comment: Your question is hard to follow without input an expected output.

Answer (score 2):

That syntax isn't valid but PHP offers a bunch of different ways to go about this anyway.

But you can use [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to make this more concise:

```
if (in_array($currentLetter, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])) {

}
```

If the letters are 0-9 you can use [`range()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to shorten this:

```
if (in_array($currentLetter, range(0,9))) {

}
```

Or, you can just check if that character is numeric. There are many ways to do this with PHP. Here I use [`ctype_digit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) you you can also use [`is_numeric()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php).

```
if (ctype_digit($currentLetter)) {

}
```

Comment: Great! It's a proper name, hence a string not a numeral so I need to use the first solution and add quotes around the numbers but it works. Thank you

    if (in_array($currentLetter, ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])) {

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match:

```
$string = "0eirieu";
if ( preg_match('/^[0-9]/', $string)) {
  echo "first is number\n";
}
```

More specifically:

```
...
$proj_title = get_the_title();
if ( preg_match('/^[0-9]/', $proj_title)) {
    //do nothing if a number
} else if ($currentLetter != $lastLetter) {
    echo '<div class="row" style="border:1px solid gray;float:left;margin-top:48px;width:100%;height:auto;clear:both;"><h3 style="text-transform:uppercase;">';
    echo $currentLetter;
    echo '</h3></div>';
    $lastLetter = $currentLetter;
}
```